# Регулярные выражения / цикл

Tags: java

```
package com.company;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String textPoems1 = "Часов однообразный бой," +
                " Томительная ночи повесть!!!" +
                " Язык для всех равно чужой" +
                " И внятный каждому, как совесть!";

        String textPoems2 = "Ура! мы ломим; гнутся шведы." +
                " О славный час! о славный вид!" +
                " Еще напор - и враг бежит." +
                " И следом конница" +
                " Пустилась." +
                " Убийством тупятся мечи," +
                " И падшими вся степь" +
                " Покрылась." +
                " Как роем черной саранчи.";

        String poem = textPoems1 + " **************** " + textPoems2;


        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\*]+");
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("!+");

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(poem);

        while (matcher.find()) {

            int count1=0;
            int count2=0;

            System.out.println(matcher.group());
            Matcher m = p.matcher(matcher.group());
            while (m.find()) {

                count1++;
                count2++;
            }

            if (count1 > count2) {System.out.println("Max: "+count1);
            } else {System.out.println("Max: "+count2);}

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ``if (***)`` - это что такое? И как можно "через оператор if" найти большее количество восклицательных знаков?

Comment: И зачем тут регулярки?

Comment: `long count = textPoems.codePoints().filter(ch -> ch == '!').count();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно эту задачу решить с помощью регулярного выражения:

```
    String textPoems1 = "Часов однообразный бой," +
            " Томительная ночи повесть!" +
            " Язык для всех равно чужой" +
            " И внятный каждому, как совесть!";

    String textPoems2 = "Ура! мы ломим; гнутся шведы." +
            " О славный час! о славный вид!" +
            " Еще напор - и враг бежит." +
            " И следом конница" +
            " Пустилась." +
            " Убийством тупятся мечи," +
            " И падшими вся степь" +
            " Покрылась." +
            " Как роем черной саранчи.";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("!");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(textPoems1);
    int count1 = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        count1++;
    }
    matcher = pattern.matcher(textPoems2);
    int count2 = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        count2++;
    }
    System.out.println(count1 + " : " + count2);
```

Comment: с помощью условия:
if (count1 > count2) {
    System.out.println(count1);
} else {
    System.out.println(count2);
}

Comment: String poem = textPoems1 + " ********** " + textPoems2;

Comment: Во-первых это не цикл, а во-вторых, в русском языке сколько восклицательных, столько и предложений. А то, что они стоят в не корректных местах, то предложения уже никак и не посчитать

Comment: Да, получается, сколько восклицательных, столько и предложений.

Answer (score 0):

раздели каждый текст и отдельно сделай

```
   text.split("!").length-1
```

самый простой способ!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "Часов однообразный бой," +
                      " \n Томительная ночи повесть!" +
                      " \n Язык для всех равно чужой" +
                      " +\n" + " И внятный каждому, как совесть!" +
                      "  **********************" +
                      "Ура! мы ломим; гнутся шведы. \n" +
                      " О славный час! о славный вид!\n" +
                      " Еще напор - и враг бежит.\" +\n" +
                      " И следом конница +\n" +
                      " Пустилась. +\n" +
                      " Убийством тупятся мечи, +\n" +
                      " И падшими вся степь +\n " +
                      "Покрылась.\n" +
                      " Как роем черной саранчи.";

        Versable verse = new VersesHolder(text).withMaxExclamationMark();

        System.out.println(verse);
    }

}

class VersesHolder {

    private static final String DELIMITER = "\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*\\*";

    private final String text;
    private final List<Verse> verses;

    VersesHolder(String text) {
        if (text == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Text should be present");
        }
        this.text = text;
        this.verses = Arrays.stream(text.split(DELIMITER)).map(Verse::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public List<Verse> getVerses() {
        return verses;
    }

    public Versable withMaxExclamationMark() {
        return verses.stream()
                     .map(VerseWithExclamationMark::new)
                     .max(Comparator.comparing(VerseWithExclamationMark::getCountOfExclamationMark))
                     .orElse(null);
    }

}

class VerseWithExclamationMark implements Versable {
    private static final char EXCLAMATION_MARK = '!';
    private final Verse verse;
    private final Long countOfExclamationMark;

    VerseWithExclamationMark(Verse verse) {
        this.verse = verse;
        this.countOfExclamationMark = verse.getText().chars().filter(ch -> ch == EXCLAMATION_MARK).count();
    }

    public Long getCountOfExclamationMark() {
        return countOfExclamationMark;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\nVerse:\n" + verse.getText() + "\nhas " + countOfExclamationMark + " exclamation mark(s)\n";
    }
}

class Verse implements Versable{
    private final String text;

    Verse(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}

interface Versable {
}
```